# Is it possible to scrape data from CORS policy website?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I want to scrape data from a website by using only javascript (no framework, nodejs or package). However when i try to get data from website, i have error on console about CORS policy.

Is it possible to overcome the problem?

Comment: Not if you continue scraping from within a web browser which respects CORS, no. You may be able to disable CORS features in the browser or just scrape it from outside a web browser and run your javascript locally as a regular program / script.

Comment: @luk2302 you are so negative. This is a problem that has two advantages. if there is a way to do that then it opens an opportunity for browser developers to fix the bugs. make web security better.

Comment: @HannaRose What? I simply do not understand what you are trying to say, what problem has two advantages? What bugs need fixing?? What security?

Comment: @HannaRose I doubt OP is asking for 0-day exploits to circumvent CORS in browsers. And if someone knew one it would not be posted on SO. So OP just asks for how to manually circumvent CORS: and the two solutions are: disable it in the browser OR not run the code within a browser.

Comment: @luk2302 My previous statement relates to something which I assume you know too. so forget it. OP: maybe you can find something that can do it using illegal chrome extension. but I really not recommend that.